# JSON is losing formatting in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a url which returns a formatted JSON. The problem is when I am echoing the $json, the json is losing its formatting. How would I avoid that

I am doing this

```
$query_string_full = http://this_is_a_dummyString.htm?key=123&ID=abc123;

$json = file_get_contents($query_string_full);
$obj = json_decode(stripslashes($json));

echo $obj;
```

Here is the output 
http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/phpDataOperation/eventcCalendar/ajax.php

I found couple of similar problems of this nature but unfortunately none of them really worked. One them is using the stripslashes. Maybe I am not using it correctly?

Comment: Can you provide the URL ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran--here it is
https://api.cityofnewyork.us/calendar/v1/search.htm?app_id=39563317&app_key=8396021a9bde2aad2eaf8ca9dbeca353&categories=City%20Government%20Office

Comment: So which data you are looking to extract from this `JSON` ?

Comment: Are you sure you have pasted the code of ajax.php here? Looks like some addslashes() function is used somewhere

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran-There is nothing specific that I want to extract. I am trying to understand where I am going wrong. It doesnt really matter which one. You can pick any one if you like

Comment: For parsing the JSON you dont need to stripslash

Comment: @SajithNair--I tried it without that function. Nothing really changed

Comment: The output of json_decode will be an object, you cannot really print it using echo, thats why I am wondering how you are getting the slashed output

Comment: If the server returns proper JSON with that URL, there is no need to postprocess this in any way, i.e. no need for `stripslashes()`. This might even wreck the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're echoing should be an object or an array, since that's what `json_decode()` would return.

Try this:

```
$query_string_full = http://this_is_a_dummyString.htm?key=123&ID=abc123;

$json = file_get_contents($query_string_full);
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo '<pre>'. json_encode($obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) .'</pre>';
```

## [Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6xK5tA)

Comment: @soum: Could you be more descriptive on what doesn't work about it? I've just added an example demonstrating that it does work...

Comment: @Travesty3--I think I got it. I have to see why I am still getting those character. But I think I understood the concept. Your direction worked. Thanks